# ms access having count syntax error

Tags: ms-access, count, having

```
SELECT hhid, 

COUNT(kind) AS h_spray

FROM pest

WHERE kind="h"
having count(spray) =0

GROUP BY hhid;
```

the output that I want to see is the number of sprays of pesticide according to their kind , but if the brand is 0 , it should not be counted

Comment: The `HAVING` clause should come after `GROUP BY`.  See [SELECT Statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208930(v=office.12).aspx).  If changing their order doesn't give you what you want, please add a few rows of sample data to your question and show us the output you want based on those data.

Comment: Is brand a column in your database?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will provide the counts of sprays with a count greater than 1.

```
SELECT hhid, COUNT(kind) AS h_spray
FROM pest
WHERE kind="h" 
GROUP BY hhid
having count(spray) > 0;
```